# Qt - How to Use Key Pressed Event for a LineEdit which accepts only the Integers

Tags: qt4, qt4.7, qt4.8, qlineedit, qkeyevent

I'm a new bie to Qt C++..  I have a **QLineEdit**. In which i have to Enter only the integers. If i press an Alphabet or any any other character my **QLineEdit** should not accept it. How to do this in qt with C++? Please Help To solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation it has already implemented in Qt. You have only to do something like this:

```
 QValidator *validator = new QIntValidator(100, 999, this);
 QLineEdit *edit = new QLineEdit(this);

 // the edit lineedit will only accept integers between 100 and 999
 edit->setValidator(validator);
```

you can read more here: [Int validator](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qintvalidator.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot...  I used a QDoubleValidator where i can make use of the decimal values too.. :-) Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: you asked for integers so i suggested *QIntValidator* =)